# Solving Problem by given Expected value and Standard daviation (with tables)

Tags: probability

500 item normally distributed with
$E[X]=68.5 kg$ and SD $\sigma=6.8 kg$

a) How many items weigh between $54kg$ and $70 kg$ ?
b) How many items weigh more than $84 kg$?

And there are given two tables with numbers named: "**Standard Normal Complementary CDF Q(z)**" **"Standard Normal CDF Phi(z)"** I have no idea what are those tables for and how to use it. Any idea? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put you on track.

$U:=\frac{X-68.5}{6.8}$ has standard normal distribution.

On b):

$P\left(X>84\right)=P\left(U>\frac{84-68.5}{6.8}\right)=1-P\left(U\leq\frac{84-68.5}{6.8}\right)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{84-68.5}{6.8}\right)$.

Comment: whats that $U$ ? and Question a) seems like something to do with $54kg$ and $70kg$ ? Sorry im bloody beginner in probability

Comment: Since you are a beginner I think that trying to get hold on these things by asking questions is not the right route. You need a good script and/or course.

Comment: @dhab i just read about gaussian distribution, and As you wrote here: $P\left(X>84\right)=P\left(U>\frac{84-68.5}{6.8}\right)=1-P\left(U\leq\frac{84-68.5}{6.8}\right)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{84-68.5}{6.8}\right)=0.0113$ I found. it its the probability so i just multiplied with 500 with it and found $5.65$. Is this the answer of question b) right ? and for question a) i did use similar method. $P\left(54<X<70\right )=...$, So now please tell im im doing right

Comment: Yes, that is the correct way to handle this. You are learning fast. For handling a) you must also be aware of the fact that the distribution of $U$ is symmetric.